# Is there any way to scan Windows XP folders for viruses from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, malware, anti-virus, ransomware

We know that Windows XP is passed away long time before. But still I like to use ( or I have no other way because some old software work only on XP). Most of the anti-virus and malware protection softwares will not install on XP. But I don't want to put my self in security risk. So how can I search the XP PC with a Windows 10 PC (connected thru LAN), where the latest update of an anti-virus is available. One way is to share the drive and scan. Anything else ?

Comment: Try : https://it.toolbox.com/question/lan-antivirus-100810

Comment: You could make the XP machine a virtual machine and keep it isolated from the internet and email (so just your games)

Comment: John, :-) Its not games. Some old apps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scan a remote machine with anywhere near the depth and efficacy of a local scan, regardless of the OSes on either side of the system.

You should not use XP on an independent machine unless you are VERY aware of the implications and know how to secure it.